# Как выделяется память под указатели?

Tags: c++

Как я понял указатель это число которое хранит в себе адрес. Получается, объявив указатель, программа резервирует память под `int` (в зависимости от разрядности)? И значит создав массив указателей длиной `N`, резервируется `N * sizeof(int)` байт?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/new-and-delete-operators?view=vs-2019

Comment: @goldstar_labs я не нашёл там ответа на свой вопрос

Comment: Если не хочется в sizeof использовать указатель на конкретный тип, то `sizeof(ptrdiff_t)`

Comment: @MBo я наверное не совсем точно описал что хочу узнать
вот например
`char* p[100];`
каждый этот указатель описывается адресом, адрес это число. значит ли что написав такую инструкцию мы заведомо резервируем для каждого указателя память равную `sizeof('тип данных под адрес')`? т.е. для массива выше `100*sizeof('тип данных под адрес')`?

Comment: Да, верно, только нельзя считать, что размер int равен размеру указателя.

Comment: @MBo спасибо, а не подскажете где можно прочитать про это подробнее?

Comment: @Black Blur Подождите, пока c++-ники подскажут ссылки на  канонический текст

Comment: я не совсем понимаю вопрос) сам по себе указатель это обычное число, размер которого равен разрядности ОС и не зависит от типа данных, на которые он указывает. объявляя указатель вы веделяете место под него, объявляя массив указателей вы выделяете N * sizeof(uintptr_t) памяти

Comment: @goldstar_labs да, я про это и спрашиваю, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Массив указателей в С++ (у вас эта метка) создается

```
type** massiv = new type*[N];
```

По количеству выделенной памяти это то же, что и

```
type** massiv = (type**)malloc(sizeof(type*)*N);
```

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно, ты что-то напутал:) Если ты создашь массив указателей длинной N (допустим, массив указателей на int), то у тебя под этот массив зарезервируется N * sizeof(int*) байт.